# How to automate checking a field in an ipa's embedded.mobileprovision?

Tags: ios, xml, scripting, ipa, app-id

I want to be able to run a script on an iOS ipa that checks a particular field in the `embedded.mobileprovision` file (it's in xml), e.g. the `application-identifier`, which appears like this:

```
    <key>Entitlements</key>
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>ABCDEFGHIJ.com.someCompany.someappID</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>ABCDEFGHIJ.*</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

So I would want the script to output that field for me like this:
`ABCDEFGHIJ.com.someCompany.someappID`

Consider that I don't want to do anything to the original ipa except copy it and then check the copy.

The manual process that needs automation:

1. Copy ipa
2. Change ipa copy's extension to .zip
3. Unzip (a Payload directory is then created)
4. Open Payload directory
5. Right click on the .app in the directory and select 'Show Package Contents'.
6. Open embedded.mobileprovision
7. Search for the application identifier and check it

Answer (score 1):

As the responder above noted, the tools to do this are very old - meaning not that you should know about them, but that some google searches will reveal mountains of information.

The IPA is a zip. Unzip it.
Find the file within that you care about. It's a very obvious path.
Use grep or some other tool to get the line you want.
etc.

Answer (score 0):

What about cp, mv, unzip,cd,grep? :)

Comment: Please expand this answer a bit more then just listing some commands. This is a very vague help for the OP.